# Is it absolutely essential to use viewport tag to adapt a web to devices?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

Hello friends to see if someone gives me a hand to tailor my web devices.

I tried to media queries and my phone (I have only one, Motorola Moto G) I managed to adapt, but I have not used the viewport tag. I just have been adapting the CSS through this media query:

Landscape:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-aspect-ratio: 13/9) {

}
```

Portrait:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (max-aspect-ratio: 13/9)  {

}
```

On my phone the web is perfect, I managed to adapt both landscape and portrait. But what happens is that I have only this phone and do not know how the page will look in other devices, putting the viewport tag is deformed giant and completely:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The problem is that I'm pretty lost with this, because to prove my page this also deformed giant appears:

http://www.responsinator.com/

The question is, resolution is 1280x720 Moto G? Why to place the viewport tag goes so distorted? I do not understand, see if someone can explain. I tried to find information on the Internet but I can not understand it.

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as *viewport label* in CSS. The CSS you posted is not valid. Remove **"landscape"** and **"Portrait"** if you have them in your code or wrap them up as comments, like this: `/* landscape */`, `/* Portrait */`. If this does not answer you question, please clarify it as it is unclear what you are asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sorry, that's not in my code, I have appointed you to see him. I edit post

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your problem. Right now we are not able to experience it, so we cannot help. The link to "responsinator" only shows a blank phone image.

Comment: Placed on the form at the top left the url of a website to test on different devices. I do not understand is that the iPhone 5 has 320px wide if that terminal has a resolution 1136 x 640 pixels. I do not know if I explain myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I *think* you're asking is that:

> Is the Viewport Tag (the meta tag) absolutely essential because it is messing up your view of your website on your device.

To answer this, lets look at the viewport tag itself:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This tells the browser to set the initial scale to 100% of the viewport window, and the width of the `body` element to that of the device, so it is telling the browser to correlate the width of the webpage `body` element to the same width as that of the device viewing it.

In short, no the viewport tag is **not** absolutely essential, but it is an extremely good idea, although you can change the settings on the `content` part of the tag such as

> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1">
> ```

or

> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
> ```

You can do no wrong reading up on the [Mozilla Developer Network page on the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) which will tell you the possible values you can set in the viewport tag. These are entirely seperate from the CSS display values and are used as a default for how the browser renders the page.

***I can not give you more specific advice without you providing a more specific issue in your question***